# Need help starting binary tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I need a nudge in the right direction. I have this coded so far >>

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class clubmember {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int id;
        String fname, lname;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("ID>");
        id = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Fname >");
        fname = input.next();

        System.out.println("lname >");
        lname = input.next();


        Person object1 = new Person(id, fname, lname);

        System.out.println(object1);


    }
}




public class Person {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;


    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(id) + ": " + firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

I need to create a binary tree that displays the member id with the name. I have looked at endless binary trees but confused how they actually grab this information then proceed with it. Can anyone give me a starting point or some example code that is similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this excellent [introduction to binary trees](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/) from the Stanford CS Library.

Comment: I understand what a binary tree is I just don't know how you tie it into use with a program. What code ties it into the program?

Comment: I don't mean to be difficult, but based on your comment it doesn't really sound like you know what a binary tree is. What is your program supposed to do? Are you meant to have a tree of persons to search? If so, you need a node class (or to shoehorn it into your person class) so that a person can have left and right children. This also means you have to have a way to order them so that one person can be "less than" or "greater than" another person. It sounds like you maybe need to compare based on the person's name...

Comment: All I have to do is make a binary tree that takes the persons and displays them in order.

Comment: How do you define the order? Given two persons, how do you decide which is "greater than" the other person?

Comment: Typically you could use an if else statement. But she wants a binary tree to do this.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. Let's say I have Person A with `id=123, firstName=John, lastName=Doe` and Person B with `id=456, firstName=Jane, lastName=Smith` . Which order would these be displayed in and why?